# A way split an Angular 4 app into user-facing and admin parts

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm designing an architecture of Angular 4 app. The application will be used by two groups of users: "end-user" and "admin".

I don't want to split the code into two separate applications, because a lot of classes for end-user will also be needed by admins (for example, to preview changes). On the other hand, no classes for admin are required for end-user.

Of course, I don't want to ship scripts for admin to end-user. So I want to have two build plans: full and reduced. This is my vision of the solution, other solutions might be better.

Let me summarize the problem: I need a way to bundle code for end-user separately. But I don't want to have two separate projects for user and admin because of shared code.

What would you recommend to do?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Are you using Angular for a client-side Web application? If so, then you only need one build and deployment. You can then use lazy loading to only load the admin piece for admin users.

Comment: @DeborahK lazy loading is probably the way to go. Could you please hint me how can I tell angular to bundle certain scripts separately? Would those scripts just start working if I upload them or do I need to register something at runtime?

Comment: See the suggestions in the answer by Mauricio. I also have a course on Angular routing you can find here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend dividing your app into 2 features modules and using the concept of lazyModules and the idea of feature modules.

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules
- https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/wiki/Routing-and-Lazy-loading-@NgModules

Using LazyModules will load a module only if the router is reached . Here you can use guards to control using a service if your user is admin or just user. More info about guards.

- https://netbasal.com/implementing-auth-guard-with-componentless-route-in-angular-b50a21f3bd77

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html